Are discussions on the editorial content of stats-wikipedia in scope for cross-validated?
Following this question and other random internet searches, I have scrolled quite a bit through the stat pages of wikipedia. Some pages are really good, but a bunch of topics are very poorly presented and/or contain factual errors and/or interpretation errors, etc.
As a consequence, I wish to invest some of my time in editing this topic on wikipedia. However, I struggle to formulate a great plan for doing so on my own, both due to the limited perspective one can have on their own, to the limitations of my knowledge, etc.
I thus wonder whether these discussions would be on-topic for cross-validated. The community includes many expert statisticians with extraordinary perspectives on statistics which would be precious in editing complex topics. At the same time, I could also see these discussions being too open and forum-like for them to be in-scope.
If these discussions would be out-of-scope here, does anyone have any ideas where I should look / how I should proceed?
Best regards

That sounds like an open-ended conversation, which would be off-topic on CV.  If you have something else in mind, it might work, I don't know.  In general, chat exists for serving that purpose.  You could even create your own, dedicated chat room for it, if you wanted.

Thank you for pointing out the chat: I wasn't aware of its existence. I guess it would be the right place.

If you haven't conducted this search and if it can be useful for your plan, you'll see that there are many questions about the correctness and interpretation of various Wikipedia articles: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=wikipedia . Maybe you should also look at the wikipedia internal processes for specific projects like yours, that might be helpful (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:WikiProject_Statistics for instance, or perhaps https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projet:Probabilit%C3%A9s_et_statistiques as I see that you probably speak French)

As you acknowledged yourself,

I could also see these discussions being too open and forum-like for them to be in-scope.

You can definitely ask questions on the contents of Wikipedia which might propel further discussion/criticism of the content in question.
But as to how to edit and how to proceed pertinent to that seemed to be not on-topic.
It has been an open secret that Wikipedia, while maintaining some good posts, is riddled with misleading or outright confusing posts, many of which have prompted questions to be asked here, including the one you cited.
gung - Reinstate Monica has provided a good advice in recommending places like Ten Fold (and yes, you can create your own room) for these discussions -- many experienced users do call by frequently and the discussion ranges from anything related to statistics, data science, conference or any "gossip, grumbles, and idle chat". In fact, we do occasionally discuss/have discussed about topics in Wikipedia, their presentations (or lack thereof) and in fact that has led to creation of new Wiki articles too by our users (eg 1)! So, if you pay a visit, then welcome in advance.

I'd certainly welcome a good place to have conversations with reasonably knowledgeable individuals about improving the content of some of the stats articles on wikipedia. The Talk sections on the pages themselves are, in my experience, a waste of time. The quality of many of the comments is very poor. I don't think I've ever had a useful response (either in text or as an action) from posting there. I only see much benefit in recording my reasons for a change in the Talk (e.g. post a suggestion for a change, wait a bit, implement suggestion myself in the absence of any response, discover the article has been re-mangled by someone else a few months later). They also aren't integrated discussions across pages. There are wikiprojects including for statistics but again I feel the environment is not really conducive to concerted attempts to converse in detail in order to try to improve the quality, though it does seem very useful as a kind of noticeboard for things to look to improve.
Stackexchange's Q&A is not the place for that discussion. It would sometimes be suitable for posting a specific question relating to some detail that arises in writing an answer, or for a reference request perhaps, so there would be some use cases but it's a discussion forum.
I'm not sure Ten Fold is quite the place, though perhaps the volume would be low enough it wouldn't derail things. Another chat room could serve but I expect it would die pretty quickly. A discord server might work, or perhaps a lemmy community might be better. Even Reddit perhaps; volume of posts would likely be better. Each of these would  need an owner or moderator (or several) of some form.

If you want to work on a specific page, it can be worth to see if people on ten-fold are interested in contributing or reviewing the changes, probably? I'll try that in the future.
